# How can cfdisk end of sector values be used to calculate the partition sizes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, partition-table, cfdisk

From **cfdisk** I am able to get statistics about the disks, namely the end sector of each of the first through 3rd partitions and the end of the free space.  I am trying to calculate the partition sizes, and something is going wrong.  When I resize some of the partitions, the size is clearly incorrect from **cfdisk** analysis after.  Please help me understand what is going wrong!

```
#!/bin/bash
#This setsetcor script takes three arguments: setsector a b c d
#Both a, b, and c are integers

a=$1; #The end (in 512 byte sectors) of the sdx1 partition
b=$2; #The end (in 512 byte sectors) of the sdx2 partition
c=$3; #The end (in 512 byte sectors) of the sdx3 partition
d=$4; #The end (in 512 byte sectors) of the free space
e=$5; #The adjustment factor

#The result a-b-c-d

printf "The end (in 512 byte sectors) of the sdx1 partition is a=%d \n" $((a))
printf "The end (in 512 byte sectors) of the sdx2 partition is b=%d \n" $((b))
printf "The end (in 512 byte sectors) of the sdx3 partition is c=%d \n" $((c))
printf "The end (in 512 byte sectors) of the free space     is d=%d \n" $((d))
printf "The adjustment factor                               is e=%d \n" $((e))
printf "The number of sectors (512-Bytes erach) for parition 3 equals %dS .  \n" $(( $((c))-$((b))+$((e))))
printf "The number of sectors (512-Bytes erach) for parition 2 equals %dS .  \n" $(( $((b))-$((a))+$((e))))
printf "The number of sectors (512-Bytes erach) for the free space is %dS .  \n" $(( $((d))-$((c))+$((e))))
printf "The number of sectors (512-Bytes erach) for the drive size is %dS .  \n" $(( 0 ))
# printf "The initial size of sdx3 is d-c+e. \n"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.